# How to filter array type of resource in Telerik MVC Scheduler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm trying to filter calendar MeetingAttendees which can have multiple users. I've built a filter and tested with various options, but it doesn't work. The basic example shows how to filter a calendar owner (which is a single value) and it works fine for me. But Attendees is an array and when I'm trying to filter that all my events disappear.

Here is my filter code:

```
var checked = $.map($("#teamMembers :checked"), function (checkbox) {
    return parseInt($(checkbox).val());
});
var filter = {
    logic: "or",
    filters: $.map(checked, function (value) {
        return {
            operator: "eq",
            field: "Attendees",
            value: value
        };
    })
};
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.dataSource.filter(filter);
```

Attendees in MeetingViewModel are loaded as an array:

```
Attendees = meeting.MeetingAttendees.Select(m => m.AttendeeID).ToArray(),
```

Here is the scheduler configuration:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Itsws.Models.MeetingViewModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(DateTime.Today)
    .Editable(editable =>
    {
        editable.TemplateName("CustomEditorTemplate");
    })
    .StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 7, 00, 00))
    .Height(600)
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();
        views.TimelineView();
    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.MeetingID);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
            })
        .Read("Meetings_Read", "Scheduler")
        .Create("Meetings_Create", "Scheduler")
        .Destroy("Meetings_Destroy", "Scheduler")
        .Update("Meetings_Update", "Scheduler")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently operator field can also be a function that does filter comparison. Here is the sample code generously provided by Telerik support.
More info here:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-filter-array-type-of-resource-(e-g-attendees)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-vertical">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.moonlight.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.moonlight.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
      <div id="team-schedule">
        <div id="attendees">
          <ul>
            <li>Alex: <input type="checkbox" id="alex" value="1"></li>
            <li>BoB: <input type="checkbox" id="bob" value="2"></li>
            <li>Charlie: <input type="checkbox" id="charlie" value="3"></li>
          </ul>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="scheduler"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
          date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
          height: 600,
          views: [
            "timelineMonth"
          ],
          timezone: "Etc/UTC",
          dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
              read: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              update: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              create: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              destroy: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                  return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
              }
            },
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "meetingID",
                fields: {
                  meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                  title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                  start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                  end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                  startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                  endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                  description: { from: "Description" },
                  recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                  recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                  recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                  roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                  attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                  isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          group: {
            resources: ["Rooms", "Attendees"],
            orientation: "vertical"
          },

          resources: [
            {
              field: "roomId",
              name: "Rooms",
              dataSource: [
                { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
              ],
              title: "Room"
            },
            {
              field: "attendees",
              name: "Attendees",
              dataSource: [
                { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
              ],
              multiple: true,
              title: "Attendees"
            }
          ]
        });

        $("#attendees :checkbox").change(function(e) {
          var checked = $.map($("#attendees :checked"), function(checkbox) {
            return parseInt($(checkbox).val());
          });

          var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

          scheduler.dataSource.filter({
            field: "attendees",
            operator: function(item, value) {
              var found = true;
              for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
                if (item.indexOf(checked[i]) < 0) {
                  found = false;
                }
              }
              return found;
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```